# NameError-- name 'logs' is not defined. Django-Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-2.0

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^logs/', include(logs.urls)),
]
```

I have written this code in main/urls.py file

code in logs/urls.py is below:-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$/', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

and i am accessing http://localhost:8000/logs

Error:- NameError name 'logs' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the module you are actually referencing before adding it to your URLs file.

Assuming `logs` is in your import path:

```
import logs
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use a string with `include` so that you don’t have to import the module;

```
url(r'^logs/', include('logs.urls')
```

Also, you should remove the slash from the end of your regex for the index view. The dollar marks the end of the string, so `r'^$/'` will never match.

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/). It should help!

`include()` function takes a list/tuple of `url()`, `path()`, `re_path()` and includes them to django routing system.

It also requires app's name: you can define it in `include(("enter here your app's name", app.urls))`
or in an app itself, in urls.py at a modular level. `app_name = 'enter here your apps'name '`

But only `include()` isn't enough, you have to define it in `path()` or smth that is used for routing (e.g `re_path()`, `url()` (*deprecated in django 2.0*))

For full details: [`include()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#include) function.

So, the full poiting to app's urls look so:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url, include
 from . import views
 from . import app

   urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^', include(("app", app.urls)), name='index'),
   ]
```

I recommend you to use `path()` and `re_path()` if you use Django 2.0 >

---

I noticed that you use regex incorrectly little bit

> url(r'^$/', views.index, name='index'),

You type `$` before `/`, it's incorrect, `$` means the end of expression and must be used in the end of expression.

---

Unfortunately I can't tell you all the details in the post. You should read Django docs. Go through [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/) for start.

I'm sure it will help!